# Уведомление на Android

Tags: php, android, fcm, android-push-notification

У меня есть сайт с регистрацией и общим чатом(php,mysql), как мне сделать так,  чтобы когда в чат кто то напишет, мне приходило уведомление на телефон с базы данных? Работаю с андроид студио, но не знаю как это реализовать. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**PUSH УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ С ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕМ FIREBASE CLOUD MESSAGES (FCM),  MySQL AND PHP DATABASE SERVER**

Устанавливаем  права в манифесте

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

В манифесте андроид приложения пишешь это

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

В *BuildGradle* прописываешь:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

В *BuildGradle Module*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
```

Нажимаем синхронизировать.

Создаем Java class *MyFirebaseInstanceIDService*

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseInsIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        //Get updated token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "New Token: " + refreshedToken);
        Log.d("firebaseid", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);


    }
}
```

Создаем новый джава класс *MyFirebaseMessagingService*

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    private static final String channelId = "default_notification_channel_id";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FROM:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        //Check if the message contains data
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        //Check if the message contains notification

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Mesage body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String body,String title) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        //Set sound of notification
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId) //NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                // .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                // .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                // .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /*ID of notification*/, notifiBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

При авторизации приложения можно отправить в БД MySQL token привязав его к конкретному пользователю.

Получать token можно из приложения андроид с помощью `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`
Запустите приложение и из лога  `Log.d(TAG, "New Token: " + refreshedToken)` заберете token.
Для упрощения занесем полученный token в MySQL в таблицу tokens.

Далее создаем *dbConnect.php*

```
<?php
    define('HOST',''); //если на хостинг закачиваете оставьте поле пустым если на компе то напишете localhost
    define('USER','сюда имя пользователя для подключения к БД');
    define('PASS','пароль пользователя');
    define('DB','tokens'); //имя БД как в примере

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
?>
```

Далее создаем *sendnotification.php*

```
<?php

 require_once('dbConnect.php');
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $title = $_POST['title'];

 $path_to_FCM = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
  $server_key = 'ваш ключ сервера';
 $sql = "SELECT token FROM tokens ";
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_row($r);
$key=$row[0]; 

$headers = array('Authorization:key='.$server_key,
                'Content-Type:application/json'
                );

$field = array('to'=>$key,
                'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message,'sound'=>'default'));

$payload = json_encode($field);

$curl_session = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $path_to_FCM); 
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload); 


$result = curl_exec($curl_session);

curl_close($curl_session);
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

**ваш ключ сервера** берем тут:

https://console.firebase.google.com/

Добавляем проект ( точно не помню но там где то вписывается имя из андроид проекта, и помните количество создаваемых проектов ограничено )

[image: Добавляем проект ( точно не помню но там где то вписывается имя из андроид проекта)]

При добавлении проекта будет файлик json. Копируем его в приложение.

Заходим в настройки:

[image: Заходим в настройки]

Вот и ключ сервера..вписываем его в код выше..

[image: Вот и ключ сервера..вписываем его в код выше..]

Создаем файл для отправки сообщения сообщения.
*sendnotification.htm*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="admin" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="sendnotification.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="message"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот и готов у нас пример для отправки push уведомления со страницы html в приложение android.
Т.е. ввел текст нажал отправить и на телефоне вылезло push уведомление.

p.s. под *Genymotion* токен не определялся, так что тестируйте на реальном андроид устройстве. Если знаете как на виртуальном протестировать пишите в комментариях!

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогла ваша информация.

Comment: А в базе данных , какую таблицу создали?

Comment: таблица tokens, поля id, token, хотя для начала можно и без БД сделать...вот сюда  $key='ваш токен'; укажи номер токена из логов...

Comment: если есть таблица  с пользователями например users...добавь туда поле token...и будет привязка токена к пользователю из БД... в коде поменять $sql = "SELECT token FROM users ";